# Terminology of function; $f(n)=(4^n-2) / 7$

Tags: terminology, elementary-functions

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and I define the function:

$$f(n) = \frac{4^n - 2}{7}$$

- Is this $f(n)$ called a quartic function?
- Is $f(n)$ a polynomial function of degree four?
- Can a polynomial be restricted to have only one variable like $n$ in this case?
- Can a polynomial even have only one term? Like $4^n$ ?

If *not*, what can be said about this function?

Comment: $4^n$ is an exponential function, which is very different than a polynomial function $n^4$.

Comment: @Bladewood I mixed up the base and the exponent. Your clarification made sense.